# Multiple Timers in Subviews

Tags: ios, objective-c, timer

I am trying to make a program that shows a bunch of different timers (around 20) all at once. Currently I am doing that with one timer in the superview that updates all of the other timers, but this is slower than a second due to other operations that are going on (drawing things, converting to hh:mm:ss, etc.). Is there a way to give each subview a timer that ticks properly?

Comment: You should probably figure out what's wrong with your code and fix that. Otherwise, you'll still have to do all these drawings and conversions, except on top of that, you'll have to track 20 individual timers and all the associated stack management require to fire each one each second. You should have absolutely *no* problem updating 20 strings at just over 1FPS. If you're below that, something else is seriously wrong.

Comment: Currently it's trying to fire each millisecond, but that may be too much. As far as the code, it's fairly simple, it's just that there is a bunch of it. I guess I just have to convert it to fire every second.